# Repeated Measures GLM with imperfect subject identifiers

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

My experiment has a binary response variable (Presence) and 5 treatment groups (Treatment), with one other 2-level factor (Glue). I used one glue type for half of each treatment group and another for the other half. I collected the Presence data on 2 different days. Due to the way the study was designed, I don't really have unique subject identifiers. Instead, each treatment group was color coded and I counted how many were present on 2 different days. My response variable (presence) is basically survival, meaning that the proportion of each treatment group that is not present on a given day is assumed dead. This is imperfect, however, because the subjects are mixed in with many other individuals (they are bees in a colony), and there is one group (out of the 10 treatment-glue combos) where I saw 1 more individual on the second day than on the first, illustrating that my sampling is not perfect. Ultimately, I'm interested in asking which treatments have higher survival (lead to higher Presence) than others, but I would also be interested in asking how this changes over time. I'm not sure how best to analyze the data. The simple way might be to separate the data into two different datasets, and analyze each date separately with:

glm(Presence~ Treatment+Glue, family="binomial")
and then do a post-hoc comparison between treatments

Alternatively, I could try to build a model with the full dataset that includes Date as a factor. If I do this, the question would be, would it be appropriate to set up my dataset so that I have a unique identifier for each bee, and then have two dates on which I measured Presence, just assuming that bees present on the 2nd day were present on the 1st? If I did this, I would have a single bee that was present on the 2nd day without being present on the 1st, due to the situation where I saw one more of that Treatment/glue combo on the 2nd day than on the first. That model would look like:

model<-glm(Presence~Treatment+Glue+Date+(1|Bee),family="binomial")

Then I would be able to use the emmeans package to compare different dates and treatments to see if presence varies between two days within a single treatment, and between treatments on the same day:
emmeans(model, pairwise~Treatment*Date)

OR is that inappropriate since I don't have unique subject identifiers? Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks for your help and time!